# How to cast string to integer in Tkinter python

Tags: python, string, tkinter, casting, integer

How to cast string from the entry box to integer in Tkinter.
I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```py
import tkinter 
from tkinter import tt

age= tkinter.Label(window, text = "How old are you?")
age.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

entry_age = tkinter.Entry(window)
Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

height = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is your height(cm): ")
height.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

entry_height = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry_height.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

weight = tkinter.Label(window, text = "your weight (kg): ")
weight.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

entry_weight = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry_weight.grid(row = 3, column = 1) 

entry_age1 = entry_age.get()

entry_age1 = int(entry_age1)


entry_heigh1t = entry_height.get()

entry_height1 = int(entry_height1)

entry_weight1 = entry_weight.get()

entry_weight1 = int(entry_weight1)
```

Comment: What is the error your getting?

Comment: ```entry_heigh1t = entry_height.get()``` I do not see any logical errors in the code but there's misspelling here

Comment: You have to wait to do the conversion until the user has entered data. You're getting the contents of the entry widget about  millisecond after creating the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Here .get() function always return anything as a string. You have to convert that into str to int.

Here is the quick example.

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

def get_number():
    text = ent.get()
    try:
        num = int(text)    # <= Focus here
        print(num)
    except:
        print("This is not number")

ent = tk.Entry(win)
ent.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

btn = tk.Button(win, text="Get Number", command=get_number)
btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Please post the error message you're getting along with some test cases as input for the Entry boxes.

entry_age.get() returns a string that can be converted into an integer using int() if the input is a number of course.

Edit after @Milena Pavlovic replied with the error:

The program won't run because as soon as it runs the statement `entry_age1 = entry_age.get()` which stores the empty string into the variable, the next statement that follows tries to convert this empty string into an integer. Empty strings go by "" which cannot be converted to integer type. Since this is invalid, it raises the value error. To resolve this, you can make the following changes:

```
if entry_age.get().isdecimal():
    entry_age1 = int(entry_age1)

if entry_height.get().isdecimal():
    entry_height1 = int(entry_height1)

if entry_weight.get().isdecimal():
    entry_weight1 = int(entry_weight1)
```

The isdecimal() function checks if the string returned by get() is a decimal and only then will it get converted into an integer and stored into the respective variables and allow you to do what you want with them.

Comment: Yes; the error is probably because you convert to int before there is any value in the Entry. So you are trying to convert an empty str to an int and the `int()` function does not allow that.

Comment: I can't run the program and enter anything in the Entry box because it shows me the following error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @MilenaPavlovic Please refer to the edited answer. Hope it gets resolved now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have another problem. When I try to apply that data in the formula it shows me the following error : TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. And here is my code: 
def basal_metabolism():
    print (447.593 + (9.247 * entry_weight1) + (3.098 * entry_height1 * 100)- (4.330 * entry_age1))

Comment: @MilenaPavlovic This is because you're still trying to multiply a string value with an integer value. Please refer to the edited code again.

Comment: Now, the entry_age1, etc. variables are created only when they're known to be numbers. Previously, we stored them first regardless of whether they were strings.

Comment: Yes, I applied what you told me. Here's what the code looks like now:

if entry_age1.isdecimal():
    entry_age1 = int(entry_age1) 

entry_height1 = entry_height.get()

if entry_height1.isdecimal():
    entry_height1 = int(entry_height1) 

entry_weight1 = entry_weight.get()

if entry_weight1.isdecimal():
    entry_weight1 = int(entry_weight1)

def basal_metabolism():
    print (447.593 + (9.247 * entry_weight1) + (3.098 * entry_height1 * 100)- (4.330 * entry_age1))


sum_bottom = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Sum", command = basal_metabolism)
sum_bottom.grid(row=5)

Comment: I couldn't quite make out what was going on in that format but I hope there are no errors now and your code runs as intended.